# How can I select a column product of a math operation in Azure Machine Learning Designer?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, designer, azure-machine-learning-service

I have created a pipeline in Azure Machine Learning that includes a **Math Operation** (natural logarithm of a column named *charges*). The next pill to the **Math Operatio**n is **Select Column in Dataset**. Since the pipeline has not ben submitted and run I cannot access the column *ln(charges)* in the pill **Select Column in Dataset**.
My problem is that if I submit it I am able to run it and see the results in the pipeline once completed, but I have found no way of accessing those results (and thus the *ln(charges)* column in Designer.

[image: Pipeline Job after submitting and running]

[image: Pipeline in designer after submitting and running the job]

**UPDATE:**

**I have found a workaround. Still in designer the column ln(charges) is not selectable but if I manually enter Ln(charges) in the select column fields it works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the procedure of the math operation in Azure ML designer to select the column to be implemented. The following procedure will help to give the column name as well as we can also give the index number of the column. This answer contains both the procedures.

[image]

We can click on edit column.

[image]

[image]

Based on the dataset which the experiment was running, both are options are mentioned in the above screen. We can choose either of the options.

[image]

To access the data, right click and go to access data and click on result_dataset

[image]

The following page will open and click on any file mentioned in the box

[image]

Click on download and open in the editor according to your wish.

[image]

It looks like the above result screen.
The below screens are the designer created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To check the final model result. Go to evaluate model and get the results in visualization manner.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very thorough explanation. I got confused because in previous updates running the pipeline would make the results accessible in the designer but it seems now not anymore.